# Seleccionar (contar) numero de repeticiones de una columna en otra tabla MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la tabla agentes la cual contiene la columna agent_id del agente como llave primaria, nombre y claves del agente, por otro lado tengo la tabla clientes la cual contiene información de los clientes y la llave primaria del agente vinculado. es decir:

```
Tabla agentes
agent_id agent_name  clave
   1     Agente 1     3455
   2     Agente 2     5678
   3     Agente 3     9876

Tabla clientes
client_id  name   city    agent_id
   1       Pedro  Mexico      2
   2       Juan   Monterrey   1
```

Necesito obtener o contar el numero de repeticiones de los agentes en la tabla clientes
he utlizado la siguiente consulta

```
select a.agent_id, 
       a.agent_name, 
       count(c.agent_id) as repeticiones 
from agents a 
inner join clients c 
WHERE a.agent_id = c.agent_id 
GROUP BY (a.agent_id)
```

Esta consulta me devuelve los siguiente:

```
agent_id agent_name repeticiones
    1      Agente 1      1
    2      Agente 2      1
```

El unico problema es que necesito que se muestren los agentes que no tienen registros en la tabla clientes en este caso el agente 3:

```
agent_id agent_name repeticiones
    1      Agente 1      1
    2      Agente 2      1
    3      Agente 3      0
```

He tratado de usar `HAVING` en lugar de `WHERE` pero no se como integrarla correctamente a mi consulta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El usar `INNER JOIN` descarta en automático los registros que de la tabla izquierda (agentes) no tienen relación con por lo menos 1 renglón de la tabla de la derecha que sería clientes.

Entonces debería bastar con:

- Cambiar por el uso de **`LEFT JOIN`** para que de este modo te regrese las filas que si tienen relación y además te regrese las filas de la tabla izquierda (agentes) que no estan relacionadas con ningún renglón de la tabla de la derecha
- Punto extra tu agrupamiento esta incorrecto (pero MySQL lo permite), pues tu debes agrupar por todas las columnas de tu **`SELECT`** menos aquellas que resultan del producto de funciones de agregación
- Además dado que usas la sintaxis de un **`JOIN`** explícito la igualación de llave primaria con llave foránea no se hace con un **`WHERE`** si no con el **`ON`**

Consulta (prueba con esta):

```
select  a.agent_id, 
        a.agent_name, 
        count(c.agent_id) as repeticiones 
from agents a 
left join clients c ON a.agent_id = c.agent_id
GROUP BY a.agent_id, a.agent_name;
```

Comment: Es correcto, muchas gracias.